# How to host an application of form .AppImage onto my server?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, frontend

So super noob here..sorry if I make any mistakes. But on my aws instance, I have downloaded an application which is of form .AppImage. Now I want to configure that aws instance as server and host a web page, which would have this tool. Is it possible? How do I go about it?

I do know how to install apache on ubuntu and get that base page working. I also know SSL and make it https instead of http. But I do not know if a web page can be configured to show .AppImage, also how do I even do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can just host an AppImage file on any web server. Just make sure the headers are sent so that the file gets downloaded rather than displayed in the browser.
`Content-Type: application/octet-stream`, `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=...`.